# SQL Server multiple REPLACE with #temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to REPLACE multiple characters in SQL Server query and want to achieve this via #temp table instead of nested REPLACE.  I got SQL code below and want to achieve result like

> ABC
>  DEF
>  GHI

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp2

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    STRING_TO_REPLACE NVARCHAR(5)
)
INSERT INTO #temp (STRING_TO_REPLACE)
VALUES            (' ')
                 ,('/')
                 ,('_') 

CREATE TABLE #temp2
(
    STRING_NAME NVARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO #temp2 (STRING_NAME)
VALUES            ('A BC')
                 ,('D/EF')
                 ,('G_HI')

SELECT REPLACE(t2.STRING_NAME,(SELECT t1.STRING_TO_REPLACE   
                               FROM #temp t1),'') 
 FROM #temp2 t2

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp2
```

I can achieve result with nested replace

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t2.STRING_NAME,'_',''),'/',''),' ','')  FROM #temp2 t2
```

but would really like to do this via #temp table.  Please can someone help me on this.
When I try to run my first code I get the following error

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 23 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,
>
> > , >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Are you trying to generate a nested select dynamically or are you trying to produce 3 (in this case) select statements to run successively.  (or something else)

Comment: I am basically trying to replace ' ' , '/' , '_'  if the all or any one of them exist in a string in any cell of the column

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way using `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT result 
FROM   #temp2 t2 
       CROSS apply (SELECT Replace(string_name, t1.string_to_replace, '') AS 
                           result 
                    FROM   #temp t1) cs 
WHERE  result <> string_name
```

**Result :**

```
result
-----
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

**Note :** This will work only if the each `string_name` has only one  `string_to_replace`

**Update :** To handle more than one `string_to_replace` in a single `string_name` here is one way using `Dynamic sql`

I have made one small change to the `#temp` table by adding a `identity` property to loop

```
IF Object_id('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE #temp 

IF Object_id('tempdb..#temp2') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE #temp2 

CREATE TABLE #temp 
  ( 
     id                INT IDENTITY(1, 1), 
     string_to_replace NVARCHAR(5) 
  ) 

INSERT INTO #temp 
            (string_to_replace) 
VALUES      (' '), 
            ('/'), 
            ('_') 

CREATE TABLE #temp2 
  ( 
     string_name NVARCHAR(5) 
  ) 

INSERT INTO #temp2 
            (string_name) 
VALUES      ('A BC'), 
            ('D/EF'), 
            ('G_HI'), 
            ('A BD_') 

DECLARE @col_list          VARCHAR(8000)= '', 
        @sql               VARCHAR(max), 
        @cntr              INT, 
        @inr               INT =1, 
        @STRING_TO_REPLACE NVARCHAR(5) 

SELECT @cntr = Max(id) 
FROM   #temp 

SET @sql = 'select ' 

WHILE @inr < = @cntr 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT @STRING_TO_REPLACE = string_to_replace 
      FROM   #temp 
      WHERE  id = @inr 

      IF @inr = 1 
        SET @col_list = 'replace (STRING_NAME,''' 
                        + @STRING_TO_REPLACE + ''','''')' 
      ELSE 
        SET @col_list = 'replace (' + @col_list + ',''' 
                        + @STRING_TO_REPLACE + ''','''')' 

      SET @inr+=1 
  END 

SET @sql += ' from #temp2' 
--print @col_list 
SET @sql = 'select ' + @col_list + ' as Result from #temp2' 

--print @sql 
EXEC (@sql)
```

**Result :**

```
Result
------
ABC
DEF
GHI
ABD
```

Comment: Problems I  think for values with multiple delimiters.

Comment: @AlexK. In sample data each row has single `string_to_replace`. In OP's query problem is in `replace` function because of `sub-query`

Comment: Prdp - your code is code but what if I need to replace multiple characters in one string.  For example if the string is A/B_C then how can I make ABC?

Comment: @kami - Just now added a note that it will not work :D. Wait will edit my answer

Comment: @kami - updated my answer to replace multiple characters in one string

Comment: @Prdp I used once dynamic solution like this +1

Answer (score 1):

The multiple replace can be achieved via a recursive CTE as per following example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp2

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    STRING_TO_REPLACE NVARCHAR(10)
    ,Pattern NVARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO #temp (STRING_TO_REPLACE, Pattern)
VALUES            (' ', '% %')
                 ,('/', '%/%')
                 ,('_', '%[_]%') ;

CREATE TABLE #temp2
(
    STRING_NAME NVARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO #temp2 (STRING_NAME)
VALUES            ('A BC')
                 ,('D/EF_F E')
                 ,('G_HI')
                 ,('XYZ');

WITH CTE_Replace AS
(
    SELECT   STRING_NAME AS OriginalString
            ,CAST(STRING_NAME AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS ReplacedString
            ,CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS StringToReplace
            ,1 AS ReplaceCount
    FROM    #temp2 ancor
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   CTE_Replace.OriginalString
            ,CAST(REPLACE(CTE_Replace.ReplacedString, rep.STRING_TO_REPLACE, '') AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS ReplacedString 
            ,CAST(rep.STRING_TO_REPLACE AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS StringToReplace
            ,CTE_Replace.ReplaceCount + 1 AS ReplaceCount
    FROM    #temp rep
    INNER JOIN CTE_Replace ON CTE_Replace.ReplacedString LIKE rep.Pattern
)
,CTE_FinalReplacedString AS
(
    SELECT  OriginalString
            ,ReplacedString
            ,ReplaceCount
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OriginalString ORDER BY ReplaceCount DESC) AS [Rank]
    FROM    CTE_Replace
)
SELECT *
FROM    CTE_FinalReplacedString
WHERE   [Rank] = 1
```

Note that `#temp` table was updated to include an extra column called `Pattern`, this column contains the search pattern to use in order to find the specific strings that has to be replaced. This was also done to simplify the join statement in the recursive CTE. Also note that in order to find the `_` character the search pattern had to be updated as `'%[_]%'`. The reason for this is because SQL Server will interpret the `_` character as a wild character instead of a specific character we are trying to find.

Comment: I wrote something like this at first but then I remember that `_` means  *Any single character.* for LIKE and put there CHARINDEX, which works perfectly fine. There is no need for 2 CTEs. +1 from me.

Comment: @gofr1 I did not think of CHARINDEX - definitely a better option :)

Answer (score 0):

replace in the table is probably easier here

```
update t2 
set t2.string_name = Replace(t2.string_name, t1.string_to_replace, '')
from       #temp2 t2 
cross join #temp1 t1
```

Comment: No error, if run that update and then `SELECT * FROM #temp2` it only changed first character from `#temp` (removes spaces).

Comment: Interesting I will take a look at it.  If I cannot fix I will delete.

Answer (score 0):

Another way with recursive CTE (full batch below):

```
--Create a sample table, you should use YourTable
CREATE TABLE #temp2 (
    STRING_NAME NVARCHAR(max)
)

INSERT INTO #temp2 (STRING_NAME)
VALUES ('A BC'),('D/EF'),('G_HI'),('J_K/L_'),('MNO')
--I add some more objects here
```

The main query:

```
;WITH replacement AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (' '),('/'),('_')
) as t(STRING_TO_REPLACE)
), cte AS (
SELECT  STRING_NAME,
        STRING_NAME as OriginalString,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY STRING_NAME) as rn,
        1 as [Level]
FROM #temp2 t2
UNION ALL
SELECT  REPLACE(c.STRING_NAME,t.STRING_TO_REPLACE,'~'),
        c.OriginalString,
        c.rn,
        [Level]+1
FROM cte c
INNER JOIN replacement t
    ON CHARINDEX(t.STRING_TO_REPLACE,c.STRING_NAME,0) > 0
)

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES  OriginalString,
                        STRING_NAME
FROM cte 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rn ORDER BY [Level] DESC)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Output:

```
OriginalString  STRING_NAME
A BC            A~BC
D/EF            D~EF
J_K/L_          J~K~L~
G_HI            G~HI
MNO             MNO
```

Comment: As I understand you need to update some table column. To do it you need to replace some characters. I'm getting you right?

Comment: Well its not really an update.  Basically I already have a table in which one of the column has reference strings.  In these strings there are all sort of character appearing put by various users like ' ' , '_', '/', '\', '-' etc.  In my query I need to show this column with another column which will be the modified view of the original column.  So in the modified column I should have cleansed reference string with not any of these character which I mentioned above.

Comment: I was hoping not to go nested REPLACE route as then I need to do lot of REPLACE typing :(

Comment: Is there any way I can use this code in my code? http://stackoverflow.com/a/39870142/1696286

Comment: I modified my query one more time. I see no reason not to try it. Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to deal with this is to download a copy of [PatExclude8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/T-SQL/117890/), a T-SQL function designed for exactly this type of task. Here's a couple examples:

```
-- remove all non-aplphabetical characters
SELECT NewString FROM #temp2 CROSS APPLY dbo.PatExclude8K(STRING_NAME,'[^A-Z]');
-- remove all spaces, forward slashes and underscores
SELECT NewString FROM #temp2 CROSS APPLY dbo.PatExclude8K(STRING_NAME,'[ /_]');
```

Both queries produce this result set:

```
NewString
------------
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found below code on stackoverflow which seems more near to what I'm trying to achieve but am struggling that how can I use this with my code

```
    declare @String varchar(max) = '(N_100-(6858)*(6858)*N_100/0_2)%N_35'

        --table containing values to be replaced
        create table #Replace 
        (
            StringToReplace varchar(100) not null primary key clustered
            ,ReplacementString varchar(100) not null    
        )

        insert into #Replace (StringToReplace, ReplacementString)
        values ('+', '~')
            ,('-', '~')
            ,('*', '~')
            ,('/', '~')
            ,('%', '~')
            ,('(', '~')
            ,(')', '~')

        select @String = replace(@String, StringToReplace, ReplacementString)
        from #Replace a

        select @String

        drop table #Replace
```

**EDIT** by gofr1

```
CREATE FUNCTION replacement
(
    @String nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max) 
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Replace TABLE (
        StringToReplace nvarchar(100),
        ReplacementString nvarchar(100)
    )

    INSERT INTO @Replace (StringToReplace, ReplacementString)
    VALUES ('+', '~')
        ,('-', '~')
        ,('*', '~')
        ,('/', '~')
        ,('%', '~')
        ,('(', '~')
        ,(')', '~')

    SELECT @String = replace(@String, StringToReplace, ReplacementString)
    FROM @Replace

    RETURN @String

END
GO
```

Then call it:

```
SELECT dbo.replacement ('A B-C/d')
```

Output:

```
A B~C~d
```

Comment: This solution works only for one string, so you need to put into function.

Comment: I add an example to your question

Comment: @gofr1 - that is cool but only problem is that I got READ ONLY access to server and not allowed to create FUNCTIONS.  Is there any thing creating TEMPORARY FUNCTIONS?

Comment: No way. If you are readonly, try my solution. It does almost the same thing but in CTE.

Comment: Ok no problem.  Thanks for you answer

Comment: Or maybe you could ask admin of this DB to add this function on server. Or if you have your own instance, connect DB you need as a linked server, and then use the function created on your instance.

Comment: That will be time consuming because of IT policies.  Can we do this in store procedure as I believe we can create temporary store procedure and then drop it at the end?

Comment: If you got read-only access, you can not create SP, functions, tables, triggers, views etc.